# ggplot2 - ordered factor stacking in inverted order in barplot with positive and negative y-values

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I am trying to build a stacked barplot and I am having trouble with the order of the stacks.

I've got the variables name, value, count, and Percent.  value is 1-7. Any percent assigned to 5, 6, or 7 is negative, and I suspect this is where the problem is but I can't figure it out.  When I plot this the order of value in the stack is 5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1.  It should be 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.  I even tried giving 5, 6, and 7 negative values but that didn't work.

This is a bare bones version.  The one I hope to produce is "fancy".  But I am stuck on this one thing.  I am always tripping up in ggplot2, even though I like it lot.

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("cloud_data_available", "cloud_data_available", 
"cloud_data_available", "cloud_data_available", "cloud_data_available", 
"cloud_data_available", "cloud_data_available", "on_premise_data_available", 
"on_premise_data_available", "on_premise_data_available", "on_premise_data_available", 
"on_premise_data_available", "on_premise_data_available", "on_premise_data_available"
), value = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), count = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
18L, 52L, 55L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 16L, 33L, 70L), Percent = c(0.7, 
1.5, 0.7, 3.7, -13.4, -38.8, -41, 1.5, 3, 3.7, 3, -11.9, -24.6, 
-52.2)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), groups = structure(list(name = c("cloud_data_available", 
"on_premise_data_available"), .rows = structure(list(1:7, 8:14), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y = Percent, fill=value, label=value))+                          
  #geom_bar(stat=", width = .5, position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack", width = .5) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Thanks, in advance!  I always learn something new when I come here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the stack is determined by the order of the levels in your ordered factor `value`. So you need to set an opposite order for the positive and negative percentages.

```
df <- df %>%
   mutate(value2 = ordered(value, c("1","2","3","4","7","6","5")))

ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y = Percent, fill=value2, label=value2))+                          
  #geom_bar(stat=", width = .5, position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack", width = .5) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: flipped col plot]

(EDIT based on OP comment): And to force the order in the legend, breaks order can be manually specified with `scale_fill_manual()`:

```
brks <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7")
colrs <- c("#960019", "#D21F3C", "#FA8072", "gray", "#D0F0C0", "#C7EA46", "#4CBB17")

ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y = Percent, fill=value2, label=value2))+                          
  #geom_bar(stat=", width = .5, position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack", width = .5) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colrs, breaks=brks)
```

[image: with custom color scale]

Comment: I like this a lot because it helps me understand ggplot2 better.  But the legend is still off, like in my original.  Applying some of the response from @Phil doesn't fix it but I bet that can be fixed, too.  I will see if I can figure it out. Thanks, @Alexlok!

Comment: Figured it out!  I just needed to define the breaks and the values and put it in scale_fill_manual:                                                                                                         
brks <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7")
colrs <- c("#960019", "#D21F3C", "#FA8072", "gray", "#4CBB17", "#C7EA46", "#D0F0C0")
scale_fill_manual(values = colrs, breaks=brks)

Comment: Actually, I changed the color values to colrs <- c("#960019", "#D21F3C", "#FA8072", "gray", "#D0F0C0", "#C7EA46", "#4CBB17").  That's a better order.  Thanks, again!

Answer (score 1):

This is a little hacky, but the only way I can think of is to split the data into your negative and positive values, and add separate layers for each side of the axis.

```
df_neg <- filter(df, value %in% c("5", "6", "7"))
df_pos <- filter(df, value %in% c("1", "2", "3", "4"))

ggplot() +                          
  geom_col(data = df_pos, aes(x = Percent, y = name, fill = value), width = .5) +
  geom_text(data = df_pos, aes(x = Percent, y = name, label = value, group = value), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_col(data = df_neg, aes(x = Percent, y = name, fill = fct_rev(value)), width = .5) +
  geom_text(data = df_neg, aes(x = Percent, y = name, label = value, group = fct_rev(value)), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1, reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to find two answers to be selected as the one?  Thanks, @Phill!  This also fixes the legend!

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Sorry, that was rhetorical question.  I just meant that you and @Alexlok both gave me excellent answers and if I could give you both green arrows, I would.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with such mixed values should you be using stacked bar chart. Try this :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y = Percent, fill=value, label = value))+        
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'dodge', swidth = .5) +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_dodge(0.9), vjust = -1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding but this needs to be a stacked chart, as requested by the person I am making it for.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @Phil and @Alexlok for their answers.  @Phil's worked but I chose @Alexlok because it taught me something about how ggplot2 works.  The final code, in order to get the legend right, ended up being:

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("cloud_data_available", "cloud_data_available", 
"cloud_data_available", "cloud_data_available", "cloud_data_available", 
"cloud_data_available", "cloud_data_available", "on_premise_data_available", 
"on_premise_data_available", "on_premise_data_available", "on_premise_data_available", 
"on_premise_data_available", "on_premise_data_available", "on_premise_data_available"
), value = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), count = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
18L, 52L, 55L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 16L, 33L, 70L), Percent = c(0.7, 
1.5, 0.7, 3.7, -13.4, -38.8, -41, 1.5, 3, 3.7, 3, -11.9, -24.6, 
-52.2)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), groups = structure(list(name = c("cloud_data_available", 
"on_premise_data_available"), .rows = structure(list(1:7, 8:14), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = "data.frame")

df <- df %>%
   mutate(value2 = ordered(value, c("1","2","3","4","7","6","5")))

brks <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7")

colrs <- c("#960019", "#D21F3C", "#FA8072", "gray", "#D0F0C0", "#C7EA46", "#4CBB17")

ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y = Percent, fill=value2, label=ifelse(abs(Percent) < 3.5, "", 
abs(Percent))))+                            
  geom_col(position = "stack", width = .5) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colrs, breaks=brks)+
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Now, of course I don't really want the label to be "value2".  I was just using that to see the order of the stacks. I now have Percents as the value on the stack. And I wanted to suppress the really small numbers for aesthetics.  So, the final product:

[image]

Thanks, again, stackoverflow community!